# Power failure during secure delete caused HDD heads to park

Tags: hard-drive

I have an HP notebook with a Hitachi hard drive.  While wiping the drive using its secure delete feature, there was a power failure.  The drive's heads went to their park position.  How do I get the heads unstuck?  This happened to me once before, same computer, and I don't remember what I did then to solve the problem.

I've run both the quick and extended HDD BIOS utilities; both passed, no error codes.  The black screen that appears on power on simply says the problem is "3F2."

Any help and suggestions welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: Its not “parked heads.” Please provide the full model number of your laptop. Do you know if any other drives exist? mSATA? Cd/dvd?

Comment: "How do I get the heads unstuck? " How do you know they are stuck?

Comment: Can you access HP recovery from the bios or use F11 during power up?

Comment: HDD heads stuck => Harddisk does not start?

Comment: The full model number is 17t-n000 CTD; the product number is L3T35AV.  The hard drive is a Hitachi 1TB (sorry, I don't have the model for that).  The machine has a DVD in addition to the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to old question in case someone else comes across this issue:

If a drive starts an ATA Secure Erase, if it loses power, it will either automatically restart the secure erase until complete or remain locked and unavailable until the ATA password is provided in which case the secure erase will restart.

Open the computer and remove the HDD power and start the computer into an OS such as linux  (bootable USB, CD, External HDD, etc) and once the BIOS completes and you boot into an OS, re-attach the HDD power. You should be able to use tools like hdparm to view the status of the drive or unlock it. If unlocked, use smartctl to see other drive status or perform HDD tests. If the unit re-starts the Secure Erase, you will not be able to interact with the drive until it completes.

The reason for removing power is because some systems won't see a locked drive (because the BIOS doesn't know the unlock ATA Security password) and many BIOSes will "freeze lock" the drive to prevent changes after POST. Also, BIOSes that are HDD password aware may NOT use the literal password string provided in the BIOS or in a commandline tool, but instead a "encrypted" or hashed value.

Optionally, an OS can put the computer into S3 sleep and wake it back up to perform a power cycle of the drive so it comes up unfrozen. This is what "PartedMagic" does.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this HP manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05260117). and [this other](https://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1048960133.pdf):

**3F2–Hard Disk 2 Error Hard disk 2 error.**

1. Check and/or replace cables.
2. Clear CMOS. (See Password security and 
   resetting CMOS on page 86.)
3. Replace the hard disk drive.